# how to register asphttp.conn component

Tags: asp-classic

I need to do enhancements to an classic asp application which uses AspHTTP.Conn.
I am trying to set the application on my system.
I have the dll, but not sure how to install and set up it on my system.
Can you please help with the steps to register the AspHTTP dll on my system.

Comment: what version of OS you have? 32bit or 64bit? what version of IIS you have?

Comment: it is windows 7 OS 64 bit with IIS 7.5 version

Answer (score 0):

Did you check AspHTTP dll documentation?
http://www.serverobjects.com/comp/asphttp3.htm
Never mind.

Answer is:

Steps could be vary, depending on library (sorry, i never used before AspHTTP dll) and on version of IIS and of course version of Operation System.

In general steps for any library are

Step 0) find proper folder where you going to store your DLL.

if DLL required only for 1 web site (let's say for "Web01" web site only), I usually keep them in folder like "X:\InetPub\Web01\Dll\"

Step 1) regsvr32 YourDLL.EXE

if you have 64 bit OS and 32 bit library (DLL) then you should run C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe.

if you have 64 bit OS and 64 bit library (DLL) then you should run C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe.

Step 2) depending on folder, where you store your DLL. if you store DLL in Windows\systemXX folder, then may be you should skip this step. Otherwise perhaps will be needed to add read & execute permission to this DLL file for user which are running your web site or application pool -- it's depending on IIS version you are using and authentication way you are using for your web site. (i always create separated users. so, for my "Web01" web site user name will be like "IUSR_Web01".

Step 3) perhaps in IIS (in IIS 6.0) will be required to add this DLL to "Web Service Extension" with Status = Allowed.